# How can i cast a dart map <String, dynamic> to <String, List<List<int>>>?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, casting

I read up some data from shared prefs and jsonDecode it into a variable called shapes.  When I inspect the shapes in the debugger it looks like the right type.  But when I assign it to the following variable "theShapes" I get errors such as  `Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, List<List<int>>>'`

```
static var theShapes = <String, List<List<int>>>{

'general': [
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
],
....
};
```

The code used to try to cast the "shapes" variable to the type of "theShapes" is like this at the moment:

```
 theShapes = shapes
      .map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, List.castFrom(value).toList()));
```

Comment: Try this:
```final shapesMap = shapes.map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, List<List<int>>.from(value)));
  theShapes = Map<String, List<List<int>>>.from(shapesMap);
```

Comment: Nice try but that code throws this error:  Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<int>'  on the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go

```
go(String data){
  final decodedData = jsonDecode(data);
  if(decodedData is Map){
    return decodedData.map<String,List<List<int>>>((key, value) => MapEntry(key as String, (value as List).map<List<int>>((e) => (e as List).map<int>((i) => i as int).toList()).toList()));
  }
  return null;
}
```